# PHP Regular expression: exclude href anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm creating a simple search for my application.

I'm using PHP regular expression replacement (preg_replace) to look for a search term (case insensitive) and add `<strong>` tags around the search term.

`preg_replace('/'.$query.'/i', '<strong>$0</strong>', $content);`

Now I'm not the greatest with regular expressions. So what would I add to the regular expression to not replace search terms that are in a `href` of an anchor tag?

That way if someone searched "info" it wouldn't change a link to "http://something.com/this_`<strong>`info`</strong>`/index.html"

Comment: Note: When placing arbitrary test into a regex pattern, you need to sanitize it first by running it through [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like so: `$re = '/'. preg_quote($query, '/') .'/i'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need conditional subpatterns] for this purpose:

```
$query = "link";
$query = preg_quote($query, '/');

$p = '/((<)(?(2)[^>]*>)(?:.*?))*?(' . $query . ')/smi';
$r = "$1<strong>$3</strong>";

$str = '<a href="/Link/foo/the_link.htm">'."\n".'A Link</a>'; // multi-line text
$nstr = preg_replace($p, $r,  $str);
var_dump( $nstr );

$str = 'Its not a Link'; // non-link text
$nstr = preg_replace($p, $r,  $str);
var_dump( $nstr );
```

#### Output: (view source)

```
string(61) "<a href="/Link/foo/the_link.htm"> 
A <strong>Link</strong></a>"
string(31) "Its not a <strong>Link</strong>"
```

PS: Above regex also takes care of multi-line replacement and more importantly it **ignores matching not only** href but any other HTML entity enclosed in `<` and `>`.

**EDIT:** If you just want to exclude `hrefs` and not all html entities then use this pattern instead of above in my answer:

```
$p = '/((<)(?(2).*?href=[^>]*>)(?:.*?))*?(' . $query . ')/smi';
```

Comment: Looks to work great, but how could this be modified to also wrap strong tags around text that isn't in a link.

Comment: I updated my answer following your comment, please see test cases for both test cases.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much anubhava for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you are ultimately after here, but from what I can, it's a sort of "search phrase" highlighting facility, which highlights keywords so to speak. If so, I suggest having a look at the Text Helper in CodeIgniter. It provides a nice little function called `highlight_phrase` and this could do what you are looking for.

The function is as follows.

```
function highlight_phrase($str, $phrase, $tag_open = '<strong>', $tag_close = '</strong>')
{
    if ($str == '')
    {
        return '';
    }

    if ($phrase != '')
    {
        return preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($phrase, '/').')/i', $tag_open."\\1".$tag_close, $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: This is good to know, as I am using the Codeigniter framework. Although let's say I search for the word "info" and in the results is the link: "http://something.com/this_info/index.html" Then preg_replace or even highlight_phrase() will convert the link to "http://something.com/this_<strong>info</strong>/index.html" causing the link to break. So I want to prevent any phrased in anchor href tag from being modified.

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional subpatterns, see explanation here: http://cz.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php

```
preg_replace("/(?(?<=href=\")([^\"]*\")|($query))/i","\\1<strong>\\2</strong>",$x);
```

In your case, if you have whole HTML, not just `href=""`, there is an easier solution using 'e' modifier, which enables you using PHP code in replacing matches

```
function termReplacer($found) {
  $found = stripslashes($found);
  if(substr($found,0,5)=="href=") return $found;
  return "<strong>$found</strong>";
}
echo preg_replace("/(?:href=)?\S*$query/e","termReplacer('\\0')",$x);
```

See example #4 here http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
If your expression is even more complex, you can use regExp even inside `termReplacer()`.

**There is a minor bug in PHP**: the `$found` parameter in `termReplacer()` needs to be stripslashed!

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for! Although there seems to be a small bug where a link is being converted after the href. So for example this code 

<a href="/view/foo">A Link</a> will convert to <a href="/view/foo" <strong>>A Link</a>

I'm not sure why a <strong> tag is being added after a href.

Comment: I have modified my answer after your clarification. I hope now it is what are you looking for.